# What does the "Raging Blood" feats first sentence mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, bloodline

Raging Blood

> Prerequisite(s): Eldritch Heritage or sorcerer bloodline class feature.
>
> Benefit: **You gain the 1st-level bloodrager bloodline power for your bloodline**. In addition, you gain the ability to enter a state similar to (but less powerful than) a bloodrager‘s bloodrage. You can enter this lesser bloodrage twice per day, for up to 4 rounds. During this lesser bloodrage, you gain a +2 morale bonus to Strength and Constitution, and no morale bonus on Will saving throws. Otherwise, this benefit is the same as the bloodrage class feature.

Okay,

My brain is on fire trying to understand this. If you have the sorcerer bloodline or the eldritch heritage (the prerequisites), how can you possibly not have the 1st level bloodline power? You get that power by the definition of having the eldritch heritage feat or being a level 1 character with the class feature.

I would assume that this is just nonsense, but the next sentence starts with "in addition" leading me to believe that the wording is purposeful and describes something I am not understanding.

If I am making a wood oracle and get the verdant bloodline ability through eldritch heritage, what does the "Raging blood" feat exactly do other than the reduced bloodrage feature. What does the first sentence mean? I'm desparately trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Yay for ambiguity!

Answer (score 14):

Bloodragers gain different powers from their bloodline than sorcerers do. For example, compare:

[Aberrant bloodrager bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/aberrant/)

> *Staggering Strike:* At 1st level, when you confirm a critical hit the target must succeed at a Fortitude saving throw or be staggered for 1 round. The DC of this save is equal to 10 + 1/2 your bloodrager level + your Constitution modifier. These effects stack with the Staggering Critical feat; the target must save against each effect individually.

[Aberrant sorcerer bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/aberrant-bloodline/)

> *Acidic Ray (Sp):* Starting at 1st level, you can fire an acidic ray as a standard action, targeting any foe within 30 feet as a ranged touch attack. The acidic ray deals 1d6 points of acid damage + 1 for every two sorcerer levels you possess. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Charisma modifier.

(Aberrant chosen solely because it was first alphabetically.) So this feat allows a sorcerer or eldritch heritor to gain the bloodrager power, in addition to the sorcerer power they already have.

However, the sorcerer verdant bloodline *does not have* any bloodrager analogue. The Raging Blood feat does not indicate what to do in this situation, and I cannot find any official commentary on the question—actually, I can’t find *any* discussion of the question, even from other players. You will have to ask your GM—I recommend either picking a similar bloodline from those available to bloodragers, or homebrewing a verdant bloodrager bloodline.

Comment: What about for my situation? and I want the verdant bloodline?

Comment: @TheGrubbler Ah, good point, missed that. Looks like there isn’t any verdant bloodrager bloodline... and I can’t find any information on what to do in that case. Looks like you’ll just have to ask your GM. Sorry.

Comment: Brutal.

Thanks for editing your answer to include that... I've been looking all over for this today...

I'll ask my DM, thanks